# Adobe Air Mouse Over Flickering Strangely

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have made an Adobe Air wrapper application that loads my current flash application on a public website. The code is simple:

```
        private var m_html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader; 

        public function MyApplication()
        {   
            m_html.width = stage.stageWidth; 
            m_html.height = stage.stageHeight;
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mywebsite.com"); 
            m_html.load(urlReq);

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addChild(m_html);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, OStageResize);
        }

        private function OnStageResize(e:Event):void
        {
            m_html.width = stage.stageWidth; 
            m_html.height = stage.stageHeight;
        }
```

Things seem to be working normally for the most part but anything that involves a mouse over (input textfields, sprite mouse overs that have pop ups, etc) are acting very jittery. For input textfields the mouse cursor will keep flickering between the normal white mouse cursor and the text input cursor. When dealing with mouse over sprites that create popups when moused over, the pop up that gets created keeps flickering.

It appears that the internal swf that Adobe Air has loaded keeps toggling between mouse over and mouse out states when the mouse is moved slighly. Is this a known problem when loading a swf inside of an AIR application? Any ways to fix this?

Comment: I think this is just because the superposition of HTML objects. Try to resize your `HTMLLoader` or your window to get all page as in a normal browser full page.

Comment: The resize already sets the htmlloader to the full stage width/height. I have also tried going full screen mode and the problem still persists.

Comment: I tested your code and I didn't have problems. Could you give me your URL to test it, if you can of course ?

Comment: http://www.blankmediagames.com/townofsalem You will notice that mousing over the input fields on the login makes the mouse jittery (flickering between white cursor mouse and the input cursor)

Comment: I tested your link, and It worked without problems. In addition, the login page is an swf object may be that's why you have the strange mouse over. Try the swf object directly in you browser : http://blankmediagames.com/TownOfSalem/Login0_7_30.swf.

Comment: Ah! Loading the swf directly fixed the problem and all of the ExternalInterface stuff still works. I figured I needed to load the index.html to get the ExternalInterface stuff to work still.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am still curious as to what exactly causes this problem though. It would be really convenient to just point the html loader to the index.html so that it loads the swf dynamically (That Login0_7_30) gets updated frequently to a new file name and I would need to push a new Adobe AIR executable each time it is updated.

Comment: I don't know why you got this, may be because your flash version ... You can use another swf as a loader for Login0_7_30.swf and then you have just to update the loader instead of you Air app, this is not ideal but it is easier ;)